# Creating a plot summing across values within time range Python

Tags: python, data-visualization

I have data on electricity outages by power company for a 10 day range as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPWjc.png) (this is a snippet, not the full dataset). Start reflects the starting time of the company's outage (as a fraction of the day--so 12:30 am on day 1 = 0.0208, etc.) and end time reflects when the power was restored. I am trying to create a graph of electricity reduction over time (MW reduction in the table), that will sum across all power companies to show an overall plot of how many Megawatts were underproduced each hour over the 10 day period.

I'm unsure what the best method to create this plot is; I tried to create a set of empty columns representing each hour on the hour, for each hour of the 10 day range and loop through like this to insert the megawatts not produced each hour, (after, I would finally sum down the columns and plot by time):

However, I'm having trouble indexing through the set of columns I need to (columns 14-277) and am also unsure if there is an easier way to do this.

Any advice would be much appreciated!

```
  for column in electricity[:,range(14,277)]:
    if electricity['START'][i] <= column & electricity['END'][i] > column:
      column[i] == electricity['MW REDUCTION FROM OUTAGE/DERATE'][i]
    else:
      column[i] == 0
```

Comment: I think I am missing something. Is there any way that for each row, you can find out what day it is? Since there is more than just one day, if the data is not ascending or descending (sorted), it is not possible to do what you are seeking, I think.

Comment: And also, if I understand you correctly, if you want **COLUMNS** you can do something like: `electricity.iloc[:,14:277]`, but if by column, you meant **ROW** (which makes more sense), you can try: `electricity.iloc[14:277, :]`,

Comment: I can convert them back into date form, but the numeric representations seemed a bit easier to me so I didn't have to `datetime.strptime` them. Also, I believe the numeric form should be fine since the number updates for the day as well (i.e. 12:30 am on day 1 is .0208, 12:30 am on day 2 is 1.0208, etc.). Also, I do mean columns! I had created empty columns and was going to insert the megawatts underproduced via the loop and then sum down the columns to get the total per hour.

Comment: Also @AmirhosseinKiani I tried using .iloc like you suggested and now have: `for i in range(1381):
  for column in wind_subset_full.iloc[:,14:277]:
    if wind_subset_full['START'][i] <= column & wind_subset_full['END'][i] > column:
      column[i] == wind_subset_full['MW REDUCTION FROM OUTAGE/DERATE'][i]
    else:
      column[i] == 0` but I'm getting the error for the "if" statement: TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe'' . Any idea how to fix this?